Can we get all the project in specific branch of Gitlab in one API
We can get all the project using https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects and then we have to iterate all the project one by one to get there branches using https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/projectsID/repository/branches
And then we can check particular project lies on that branch or not.
This is very time consuming process.
Do we have some API that directly give all the project that is associate to particular branch.
